# Asynchronous contenteditable validation

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, contenteditable

I am building an application that need an input where some words need to be colored.

I quickly began to look at a `contenteditable` element as suggested in various posts.

For my validation, I have a sample of words that are good and all the others are bad.

Here is how I do it :

- Client html page :
  I enter text on a `<p id="input" contenteditable="true">`
- onkeyup :
  I call `parseInput()` (I also do some work with setTimeout to prevent calling this function on each keyup)
- `parseInput()` :
  I get all text in the input, I split it by whitespace to get each words.
  For each one I insert around this word a `<span>` with class : `ok`, `nok`, `check`. And I call the asynchronous validation with `callValidation()`.
- `callValidation()` :
  I send all words that need to be checked to a server and I get for each word a `true`/`false`. With that I change all the `check` classes inside the input by `ok` or `nok`.

(I will do a fiddle if that's necessary)

I find that inserting html with class to later modify them is a bit dirty but I wasn't able to find a better way...
Do you think there is a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

i think a better way is to sent the word to the server and the answer is the HTML snippet with the correct class!

Comment: I see what you mean, but if the answers from the server is long the user will not have any informations. That's why I made a transition class